# AlertDialog: как передать из данные и назначить собственную xml разметку?

Tags: android, android-studio

Я заполняю Linear Layout в ScrollView кнопками. Генерирую к каждой кнопке Id и присваиваю Tag. В зависимости от того, какая кнопка нажата пользователем- выведется определенный текст в AlertDialog. Текст уже определен в массиве строк. Кнопки хранятся в массиве кнопок и каждая имеет сгенерированный id и Tag. Это обработчик нажатия кнопки в activity, из которой нужно вызвать AlertDialog:

```
View.OnClickListener oclBtn1= new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }
```

};

А это код метода в activity вызова диалога, в котором я хочу определить содержание 3-x TextView в зависимости от нажатой кнопки в Activity:

```
public void createAndShowDialog(String title, String message1, String message2) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
```

}

Вопрос в том, как реализовать вызов этого метода в oclBtn1, назначить созданному диалогу свою xml разметку и вложить входные данные в метод(строки) из уже созданных массивов, в TextView  в xml разметке?

Буду рад любым ответам, так как я еще совсем новичок в Android Studio.
Если вы видете, что что-то реализовано очень не рационально, то предлагайте свои варианты. Массив кнопок создан потому, что в каждой ячейке есть по 4 кнопки, которые через lnInflater в цикле получают свои id и tag, и обработку в oclBtn1.

Comment: Зачем кнопки держать в массиве? Я правильно понимаю что надо отловить нажатие кнопки и показать диалог с текстом? Текст зависит от нажатой кнопки?

Answer (score 1):

Могу подсказать как создается Dialog со своей разметкой:

```
    public class YourDialog extends Dialog {
        private Button buttonClose;
        private TextView textView1;
        private TextView textView2;

        public YourDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
            super(context);
            setContentView(R.layout.your_dialog_layout);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            buttonClose = findViewById(R.id.buttonClose);
            textView1= findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            buttonClose.setOnClickListener(getOnClickListener());
        }

       public void setTextForTextView1(String text){
            textView1.setText(text);
       }

        private View.OnClickListener getOnClickListener() {
            return new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dismiss();
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы совсем новичок, рекомендую сразу начинать делать все "правильно", через `DialogFragment`.

Класс выглядит примерно так:

```
public class DialogCustom extends DialogFragment { 
    public static final String TYPE = "type"; 
    public static final String DATA = "data"; 

    //идентификаторы разных диалогов
    public static final int EXIT = 1; 
    public static final int HELP = 2;     

// интерфэйс для обратной связи из диалога
    private DialogCallback dialogCallback;     

public interface DialogCallback { 
    void dialogCallback(int result, String resultString); //любые ваши переменные
} 

//Два разных метода для приёма разных параметров (по потребности можно больше)
public static DialogCustom newInstance(int type) { 
    Bundle args = new Bundle(); 
    args.putInt(TYPE, type); 
    DialogCustom fragment = new DialogCustom(); 
    fragment.setArguments(args); 
    return fragment; 
} 

public static DialogCustom newInstance(int type, String data) { 
    Bundle args = new Bundle(); 
    args.putInt(TYPE, type); 
    args.putInt(DATA, data); 
    DialogCustom fragment = new DialogCustom(); 
    fragment.setArguments(args); 
    return fragment; 
}
//выбор нужного диалога
@NonNull 
@Override 
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {     
    switch (getArguments().getInt(TYPE)) { 
        case EXIT: 
            return exitDialog(); 
        case HELP: 
            return helpDialog(); 
    } 
    return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState); 
}
//пример диалога
private Dialog exitDialog() { 
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()); 
    final View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_exit, null, false); 
    adb.setView(v); 
    v.findViewById(R.id.btn1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View v) { 
          //ваш код
        } 
    }); 
    ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message)).setText("ваш текст");
    Dialog dialog = adb.create(); 
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true); 
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    return dialog; 
}

//---Инциализация колбэка-— 
@TargetApi(23) 
@Override 
public void onAttach(Context context) { 
    super.onAttach(context); 
    try { 
        dialogCallback = (DialogCallback) context; 
    } catch (ClassCastException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
} 

"deprecation" 
@Override 
public void onAttach(Activity activity) { 
    super.onAttach(activity); 
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) { 
        try { 
            dialogCallback = (DialogCallback) activity; 
        } catch (ClassCastException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
    } 
}

@Override 
public void onDetach() { 
    super.onDetach(); 
    if (dialogCallback != null) dialogCallback = null; 
}
}
```

**Использование.** В нужном месте вызвать

```
DialogCustom.newInstance(DialogCustom.HELP,"help")
     .show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"dialog");
```

Если надо вернуть из диалога результаты, в нужном его месте используем `interface`:

```
dialogCallback.dialogCallback(1,"success");
```