# По нажатию на элемент из GridView вызвать Dialog

Tags: android, android-studio

У меня есть activity с gridView и по нажатии на картинку в gridView должен появится DialogFragment.

```
achiAdapter=new AchievementAdapter(this, products, new AchievementAdapter.BtnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBtnClick(int position) {
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            ActivityInfoAboutAchievement Info = new ActivityInfoAboutAchievement();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("num", position );
            args.putString("name", names[position] );
            Info.setArguments(args);
            Info.show(manager, "dialog");

        }
    });
    gv=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.GridAchievements);
    gv.setAdapter(achiAdapter);
    adjustGrid();
    }
```

DialogFragment:

```
public class ActivityInfoAboutAchievement extends DialogFragment {
String[] discribe1;
String[] message1;

@NonNull
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.info_about_achienement, null, false);
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Name_of_achi)).setText(args.getString("name"));
    builder.setView(v);
    Dialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
}
```

}

Вопрос:
При нажатии на элемент экран затемняется, но ничего не высвечивается. Задумывалось, что появятся 3 textView на фоне готового Drawable. Сама картинка уже присутствует в нужном виде в info_about_achienement, из которого мы разметку считывали, но правильно ли это? Или нужен отдельный xml содержащий чисто фон будущего Dialog? И что здесь не так, почему ничего так и не появляется на экране?

Так как я новичок, то ответ без конкретного примера я вряд ли пойму. Но заранее спасибо за все предложения :)

Comment: прогрессивный метод- использовать `RecyclerView` с `GridLayoutManager` и прописывать `onClick` во `ViewHolder`.  `DialogFragment` посмотрите здесь как делать лучше: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/847791/alertdialog-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-xml-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83/847882#847882 . А бэк выставлять `view.setBackgrondResource(...)`

Comment: @Jarvis_J А можно ли не переделывать пока на RecyclerView? Разве здесь тоже не существуют методы реализации поставленных задач? Но за подсказку спасибо

Comment: можно как удобно. Это был ответ скорее на третий вопрос) пропишите `onClick` в `getView(...){...}`

Comment: @Jarvis_J Советы помогли, все заработало. Только DialogFragment так и не отобразился. Хотя background устанавливал.

Comment: хорошо) если у вас новый вопрос - задайте его или поясните вкратце здесь, что не получилось

Comment: @Jarvis_J Я вопрос правил, так что там сейчас актуальная проблема)

Comment: перенесите ваш код фрагмента и `onCreate` в `onCreateDialog`